# iOS tableviewcell overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to overlay an imageview contained in a custom section header.
Tapping header opens grouped cells. Have all that working, but need to have an arrow pointing down over the first cell, see pic
[image]

Answer (score 0):

worked it out, too simple don't know why it didn't occur to me earlier
add the image it the cell (first index) and not the section header